# Translation of English sentences into First order logic

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers, logic-translation

I need some help translating the following English sentences to predicate logic. I want to make sure I'm doing it correctly.

1. Every duck whose all ducklings cannot swim is worried.

My attempt: **∀X(∀Y (duck(X)∧duckling(Y,X)∧ cannotswim(Y)) → worried(X))**

2. Every duck cannot swim.

My attempt: **∀X (duck(X) → cannotswim(X))**

3. Every duck who has a yellow duckling is yellow.

My attempt: **∀X(∀Y (duck(X)∧duckling(Y,X)∧yellow(Y)) → yellow(X))**

Goal: "Every yellow duck is worried"

**∀X( (duck(X) ∧ yellow(X)) → worried(X))**

Are any of these incorrect or do I seem to be doing it OK?

Comment: Where is the negation in 1?

Comment: sorry it should be cannotswim(X) in all cases.. will edit it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In 1: To say that all the ducklings of $x$ cannot swim you need:

$$\forall y (duckling(y,x) \rightarrow cannotswim(y))$$

and hence you end up with:

$$\forall x((duck(x) \land \forall y (duckling(y,x) \rightarrow cannotswim(y))) \rightarrow worried(x))$$

If you mean that a duck is worried as soon as *any one* (i.e *some* of its ducklings cannot swim, it would be:

$$\forall x((duck(x) \land \exists y (duckling(y,x) \land cannotswim(y))) \rightarrow worried(x))$$

or equivalently:

$$\forall x \forall y ((duck(x) \land duckling(y,x) \land cannotswim(y)) \rightarrow worried(x))$$

(you can think of the latter as: 'for any duck and duckling pair where the duckling cannot swim, the duck is worried')

In 3 you also just need *some* yellow duckling, so you should get:

$$\forall x (\exists y(duck(x) \land duckling(y,x) \land yellow(y)) \rightarrow yellow(x))$$

or equivalently:

$$\forall x \forall y((duck(x) \land duckling(y,x) \land yellow(y)) \rightarrow yellow(x))$$

(you can think of the latter as: 'for any duck and duckling pair where the duckling is yellow, the duck is yellow as well')

Your 2. is fine, and your conclusion is symbolized correctly as well

Comment: it's not all the ducklings. It is meant that "if a duck has some ducklings that cannot swim, then the mother duck is worried"

Comment: Hmm, that's not what it sounds like to me, but I'll edit my answer ...

Comment: Ok so for one should it be ∀x(∃y(duckling(y,x)→cannotswim(y))→worried(x))

Comment: @confucious No, that first $\rightarrow$ should be an $\land$

Comment: actually what you did is correct. I had an extra doubt .. so clarified.. thanks :)

Comment: why is there an implication symbol in first one and an "&" symbol in 2nd case. I dont understand that. Also are my other attempts correct?

Comment: @confucious 'All P are Q' is $\forall x (P(x) \rightarrow Q(x))$, but 'Some P are Q' is $\exists x (P(x) \land Q(x))$ ... if you translate the logic back to English you'll see that this makes sense.

Comment: ohhh.. now I understand. This was breaking my head for a while now. Thanks for clearing it out :) So the last one "Every yellow duck is worried" would be 

∀X( (duck(X) → yellow(X)) → worried(X)) ??

Comment: @confucious No, you had that right at first. It's of the *form* $\forall x (P(x) \rightarrow Q(x))$, but your $P(x)$ in that case is 'yellow duck',, so that's why you use $yellow(x) \land duck(x)$ in the place of the $P(x)$.  P.s. logging off .... good luck!

Comment: oh.. this is quite tricky. Thanks a ton!

Comment: Actually you have left a minor part in the 1st rule. The predicate duck(X) wasn't mentioned in the head part of the rule that you defined.

Comment: @confucious Yes, good eyes!  I'll correct it.

Comment: Thank u so much